# Using list as a positional parameter in JPA query

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, sql-injection, jpql

I want to know if it's possible to pass in a list as a parameter in native queries.
When search up online, an article in [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-query-parameters) has exactly what I want to do:
[Collection-Valued Positional Parameters usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/of3ef.png)

I did the exact same thing, except that in the article, they used "createQuery" and I used "createNativeQuery". Not sure if this is the reason why mine is not working.

Answer (score 0):

CreateQuery means JPQL was passed in which is parsed and modified into SQL, which allows it to break the collection parameter into its components to pass each into the SQL statement. CreateNativeQuery uses your SQL which isn't modified, and JDBC doesn't understand collections so requires parameters broken up into individual arguments in the SQL. You have to do it yourself and dynamically build the SQL based on the number of parameters in the collection.

There are other questions with solutions that touch on other options, such as using SQL within criteria or JPQL queries that can let you get the best of both.

Comment: The problem with criteria builder is that it seems like I need a java class for that.
For example:
`
  CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

  CriteriaQuery<Country> q = cb.createQuery(Country.class);
  Root<Country> c = q.from(Country.class);
  q.select(c);
`
where we need to do something like `q.from(Country.class)`, what if I don't have that kind of java class?

Comment: JPA's premise is that most if not all data tables are mapped to entities, and you start with those entities to frame queries. If you don't have the tables needed to form the query mapped as entities, you can still get by, but it will be provider specific options to get chunks of native sql into your JPQL/Criteria queries. Orm allows almost anything. In a pinch though, while I do not recommend it, you can dynamically write your own SQL to handle variable sets of parameters within lists and just use em.createNativeQuery to execute it. Show the query in question if you want input/advice